# Intraweb class not found at runtime

Tags: c++, c++builder, intraweb

I've beenworking with the IntraWeb framework on Borland C++Builder. Sometimes it happens that an application crashes because of a strange uncaught exception:

```
An unhandled application error has occured within My IntraWeb Application. 
...
Error message raised by the application: Class TIWTimer not found
```

This happens when a new session is started. For example, by entering the address in a browser.
Also, the message appears in the classic IntraWeb error web page

The class that cannot be found is either TIWTimer or TIWButton but I think this is irrelevant.

The problem seems to occur randomly and sometimes goes away with a rebuild, but other times it will go away by rewriting the code or starting from a new project.

So, the question is, how come the link error is not found at link-time?

Why does it occur at all, since those classes belong to the standard IW library?

Has anyone had the same issue?

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use Intraweb XII in C++Builder XE2, it has good improvement and bug fixes.
in this version you can assign urls to forms, for example:
 myhost/login.htm or myhost/login.aspx

for more information see [this](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/Blog/20100503C.EN.aspx)

Comment: I think I found the solution. it's the order of includes in the main page's class.